# Grep search for words containing capital letters in Unicode

Tags: grep, unicode

After some searching, I found a `grep` command that will find words containing capital letters, and list them without duplicates:

```
grep -hoP "\w*[[:upper:]]+\w*" * | sort -u
```

However, when it comes to words that contain characters such as `ê`, it seems that grep returns the word only up to that character, ignoring the character and anything afterward.  My text is encoded as `UTF-8`, and I'm guessing the problem lies in my search criteria.

Is there a simple solution, for one who knows next to nothing about `grep`?

Comment: That does indeed work for the remaining characters in a word.  Thanks.  As you supposed, though, it does not work when the first letter is a special character.  It likely won't be a problem in my case, though if there is a way to detect them all, that will be even better.

Comment: Not sure what happened to the comment and link that someone posted, but I've been playing around with the suggestions therein, and have had some success with this: grep -hoPw "\p{Lu}+\p{L}*" * | sort -u

Comment: can you give me some samples so that I can have a test, please?

Comment: I do wonder if this is just a matter of setting the right locale. Setting the locale to `ISO-8859-1` works for me, you can check this [online](https://rextester.com/WXVGJ5873)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with `-P` that enables Perl regexp capabilities and then specify your unicode characters range as a class of characters like below as example (find your language Unicode to replace in character class below).

```
grep -oP '\w*[\x00-\x99]+\w*' infile
```